# How to translate pages that contain fontawesome with Google Translate?

Tags: font-awesome, google-translate

Is there a way to make Google Translate work on pages that contain fontawesome?

- Buttons with images are being split into two
- fonts using the fontawesome classes and i tag are not shown

For example:

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=th&u=fontawesome.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this problem is caused because google did not have access to cross site scripting font elements on my web site.

Once I added the google translate scripts to my site everything works perfectly (well, except it's not changing the language direction ltr and rtl by default)

Comment: Where did you find the Google Translate script?